# knockout.js add visibility observable based on css class

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I want to make an HTML element visible based on whether or not another element on the page has a certain class:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;          

    this.showElement = ko.computed(function() {            
        return $('#history').hasClass('active');
    }, this);
}

<li data-bind="visible: showElement">Element Text</li>
<div id="summary" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
<div id="history" class="tab-pane fade in"></div>
```

Any time a tab-pane is clicked, that tab gets the 'active' class.  Depending on which tab is active, I'd like to either hide or show the li element.  I feel like I'm close, but missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing that. The `showElement` property has no dependencies on any other observables in your view model so it will never get updated.

You should change it so the `active` class will be applied based on what is selected in your view model.  Then you can have your `Element Text` appear when it should.

Add bindings to your divs to apply the `active` class based on some conditions and set your element to be visible based on the condition you want:

```
<div id="summary" class="tab-pane"
     data-bind="click: select, css: { active: summaryActive }">SUMMARY</div>
<div id="history" class="tab-pane"
     data-bind="click: select, css: { active: historyActive }">HISTORY</div>

<li data-bind="visible: historyActive">Element Text</li>
```

Then set those conditions in your view model:

```
self.selected = ko.observable(null);
self.summaryActive = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selected() === 'summary';
});
self.historyActive = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selected() === 'history';
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgtkw/1/)